# Use PHPLinq in codeigniter

Tags: php, linq, codeigniter-2

Does anyone know how I can use the [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/releases/view/10085) in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not specifically answering your question, I have used another PHP Linq libray [Phinq](https://github.com/tmont/phinq) within CodeIgniter with no problems.

For that you just need to add the files to your third_party folder and then just have either a little helper function to include each of them or an autoload library.

Phinq makes use of namespaces so be sure to

```
use Phinq\Phinq;
```

in the files where you want to use it.